# Question on Gauss's geometric interpretation of "spherical functions"

Tags: geometry, electromagnetism, gauss

In the physics chapter of his biography of Gauss, W.K. Buhler writes the following:

> Expansions into series are frequent and important in potential theory. So it does not come as a surprise that spherical functions, first introduced by Legendre, were Gauss's most useful tool. Gauss was interested in these and other special functions; among the posthumously published papers is a geometric interpretation of the spherical functions which Gauss developed in connection with electrodynamic considerations. He remarks that the individual elements in the expansion into spherical functions can be interpreted as dipolic, quadrupolic, etc., contributions.

Looking into volume 5 of Gauss's works, I saw the fragment "on spherical functions" (p.630-631 there), in which I think part [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qiw4D.png) is about the algebraic/analytic aspects of [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics), and part [2], entitled "geometric meaning of the spherical functions", is the fragment I believe Buhler is refering to. Just to put all this in context, I think this interpretation is related to [Laplace multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion_(potential)), in which dipolic fields decay as $r^{-3}$, quadruploic fields as $r^{-4}$ and etc. Gauss's interpretation is related to the angular dependence of those fields/potentials, which is relevant to diverse themes such as the description of Earth magnetic field (this was Gauss's original motivation) and the hydrogen atom problem in quantum mechanics.

What striked me the most in fragment [2] is that Gauss apparently carries on his geometric interpretation to spherical functions of the fourth and fifth order, cases in which one cannot visualize its generation by collection of positive/negative charges in 3-dimensional euclidean space, but rather has to describe it by hypercubes in higher dimensions. However, I was not able to understand much from what Gauss wrote, and especially his notation was unclear to me.

So I added here a translation and a pic of this short fragment:

> **Geometric meaning of spherical functions:** Let $P$ be an indefinite point and $A,B,C,D$ be specified points. **Spherical function of the first order**: $\alpha cosPA$. **Second order**: $\alpha cos PA cos PC + \delta cos PB cos PD$, where $A,B,C,D$ refer to four faces of the regular octahedron. **Third order**:$\alpha cos PA cos PB cos PC +\delta cosPA' cos PB' cosPC'$, where $A,B,C$ in one largest circle. $A',B',C'$ lie in another largest circle in such a way that $AB = BC = CA = A'B' = B'C' = C'A' = 120°$ and both circles intersect at right angles. **Fourth order**: Aggregate of three products of four cosines each; the three largest circles intersect at right angles. **Fifth order**: Aggregate of three products of five cosines each. The three largest circles intersect at one point.

[image]

There is no reference to high dimensional spaces here, but even if this fragment does not introduce it, the correctness of Gauss's statements here need to be checked. I think this is another interesting point in his unpublished works that has not recieved attention. But the whole notation there is very unclear to me; therefore I'd like to get some help here by anyone who is more familiar than me with the theory of spherical harmonics.

**Update:**

- I think I got some clue about the structure of Gauss's geometric interpretation from the drawing in this fragment. After some thoughts, I think this drawing depicts four point $A,B,C,D$ at longitudes $0°,90°,180°,270°$ and all at the same latitude $45°$, as seen from the pole (latitude $90°$) of the sphere (in a kind of "top view"). This speculation is consistent with the angle $60°$ that also appears in this drawing: the [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between two adjacent points corresponds exactly to central angle of $60°$.
- I searched for additional clues at the relavent treatises on Gauss by later mathematicians, and I found a useful reference in Harald Geppert's treatise "about Gauss's work on mechanics and potential theory". It refers to E.W Hobson's book "the theory of spherical and ellipsoidal harmonics" (available on internet archive). Articles 81-84 in this book deal with "Maxwell's theory of poles" and on article 84 the author writes:

> The idea of determining harmonics by the position of the poles was suggested by Gauss*, but was first developed by Maxwell. An equivalent analytical theory is contained in a memoir by Clebsch.

Under the asterisk (*), Hobson refers to the same page in Gauss's Nachlass that appears here.

Comment: Was it not the case that *higher dimensional* or n-dimensional space beyond finite Euclidean space developed after Gauss'? For example, Hilbert space generalizes to infinite dimensions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Comment: @DJohnson - Gauss published nothing during his lifetime about n-dimensional spaces, but there are a few indications in his unpublished papers that he thought about such things. Also, [my post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14908/what-was-gausss-algorithmic-method-to-solve-a-certain-nearest-neighbour-search) show that Gauss dealt with high dimensional spaces in his lectures from the 1850s. Of course, the first mathematician that fully expressed the idea of n-dimensional geometry was Bernhard Riemann.

Comment: And, of course, Riemann and Gauss were contemporaries.

Comment: What I am really struggling with is Gauss's notation in this fragment; only after I will understand it I will be in a position to begin checking his statements. If, for example, angle $PA$ is the length of large circle connecting the projections of the points P and A onto the unit sphere, and if A is defined to be one of the poles (intersection of z axis with the sphere), than his result for spherical function of the first order coincides with the potential of a dipole. But than he says $A,B,C,D$ are faces of octahedron , so I am completely lost in my attempt.

Comment: Your comment suggests the long-standing, impossible challenge of *squaring the circle*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle

Comment: @DJohnson, yes, in fact, Riemann was Gauss' student. :)

Comment: Side remark: "the three large circles" (2x) should be "the three large**st** circles"